# Ignored files show up in changes not staged for commit

Tags: git, gitignore

I have added

```
media/
build/
```

in.git/info/exclude, and after that deleted (git rm) both directories. I need these rules in the exlude file rather than .gitignore because I only want that repo to ignore it, not the blessed repo or any other repo. However running

```
git status
```

still lists the deletion of all the contents of both dirs. How do I prevent this?

**EDIT**

Here's what I have; a private repo on github, my local installation, some colleagues with their own local installation, and a server. The site is a Django site, so for performance the static media files are kept separate from the actual Django installation.

However, locally we have the media file inside the Django root. Therefor the media directory is also in the blessed repo at github. But the server should ignore the directory, this is what I was trying to accomplish by adding the directory to the exclude file. But even though it's in there, it doesn't seem to get ignored.

adymitruk was right about the build folder, I've added it to my general .ignore file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you deleted both the directories - so did you `git rm` them and commit it so that they are removed from the repo ( unversioned ) and not just removed in your working directory. Because, as long as they are versioned, `git status` will still show modifications to these directories ( in this case their deletion ) irrespective of the ignore.

Comment: I've tried both, and in both cases git status shows the files after deletion. But, from what you say, I understand that even though a file is ignored it can still be "versioned"? Than is there a way to achieve what I want, that the files are no longer ignored or versioned?

Comment: @Jasper Kennis - what do you mean you have tried both? Have you done `git rm media/` and `git commit` that deletions?

Comment: To be more exact I've run git rm -r media/ and rm -rf media/. Maybe the problem is in the recursive action, and only the folder itself is being ignored, not it's contents?

Comment: @Jasper Kennis - you have to commit it. `git rm` doesn't mean the deletion is committed and the folder is removed from the repo. Use `git status` to see the condition of the repo and you must see that the folder is deleted and ready for commit.

Comment: I DON'T want the changes to be committed. And I don't want them to show up in git status. Please read the question again; the media/ folder is in .git/info/exclude but despite that it shows up in git status and commits.

Comment: @Jasper Kennis - If you already have them in the repo, then you have to delete and commit them to make git START IGNORING them from hence forth. You have to commit the deletion FIRST to remove it and only then the ignore will work.

Comment: @manojlds let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2285/discussion-between-jasper-kennis-and-manojlds)

Comment: For those passing later, read the discussion we had. Manojlds has been a really great help to me, tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Master is not a clone. It's a branch in a repo. I'm guessing you are referring to a blessed repository.

There are many ways to accomplish this:

1. Make a branch where you delete the folders explicitly. Subsequent merges from other branches into this one will have conflicts due to changes in those folders. Use the recursive strategy with the "ours" option. Your branch will look like you intend.
2. Make a complex smudge/clean script. I wouldn't go this route.
3. Never stage changes to those files.

The greater issue is your workflow. There 2 issues that I see:

1. You have media as part of the repository where you store code. This usually involves large files and is a great burden when cloning, checking out, etc. Consider using submodules for that directory and only populating them when you need to access the media.
2. "Build" sounds like it's aritfacts? If they are build artifacts, they don't belong in the source repository. Manage them separately with whatever deploy scheme/tools you have. You can regenerate them from the source whenever you want. Rely on tagging to mark what was built/when/why.

I'm making a lot of assumptions about your workflow. But hopefully this will help you in some way.

Cheers

Comment: You are making many assumptions actually but that's probably because my information is insufficient. I'll add the extra info to the question.

You are right about my workflow, this is a result of how the project has come to grow. I've taken over the development for this Django site and went from the svn to git because I like git more. To get the site running locally quickly I've added the media folder to my site root, instead, I should probably put it next to it, but I like it this way.

It's a matter of business value vs efficiency vs my appetite, although in the end this is costing me time:p